# How do I solve this algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

The question goes, solve in real number.

$x^5 - 5 x^3y - 5x^2 + 5xy^2 + 5y = 16 \tag{1}$

$ y^5 + 5xy^3 + 5y^2 + 5x^2y + 5x = -57 \tag{2}$

I tried simplifying the first equation to,
$$ x^5 + 5\left[ \left(xy+1 \right) \left( y - x^2 \right) \right] = 16 $$

and second equation to, 
$$ y^5 + 5 \left[ \left(xy+1 \right) \left( y^2 + x \right) \right] = -57$$

I know not much efforts shown, but this is where I'm stuck. Any hints on where do I go from here?

Thanks

Comment: Where is this problem from?  Using a basic Bezout bound, there could be $25$ solutions.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm guessing this is contest/contest prep; there is likely no way to "solve for" the eventual solution, but uniqueness can be inferred from inequalities, and the numbers are pleasant. Anyway, in the third quadrant, the curves are apparently separated by the ray $y=-x,$ I imagine that observation can be firmed up. Then just the fourth quadrant remains

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik My man, what sorcery did you use?

Comment: Oops I made an error--the answer given is incorrect and there may be more than one solution.   I determined the real solutions to the resultant of the two polynomials.

Comment: Apparently, $(x,y)=(1,-2)$ is the unique real solution.

Comment: @Batominovski How did you find it and show uniqueness?

Comment: I didn't find it.  WolframAlpha did, and I have no clue how to find it manually.

Comment: @William Is the posted question the original problem, or is it something you derived while attempting to solve some other problem?

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- It seems that Batominovski's comment about $(1,-2)$ is true. One has $$x^5+5(xy+1)(y-x^2)=16\\y^5+5(xy+1)(y^2+x)=-57$$ From which 
$$\frac{y^2+x}{y-x^2}=\frac{y^5+57}{x^5-16}\qquad(1)$$
 A necessary condition for solutions $(x,y)$ is equality $(1)$. However it is not suffisant because if not it would be an infinity of solutions. Making separately

$$\frac{y^2+x}{y-x^2}=a\qquad(2)$$ $$\frac{y^5+57}{x^5-16}=a\qquad(3)$$ we have in $(2)$ a conic, hyperbola, ellipse, circle ($a=1$) and two lines ($a=-1$) while in $(3)$ there is a quintic.The corresponding graphics are suggestive in order to search solutions. In any case the graphics of the given equations (in the attached figure green and black respectively) also give $(1,-2)$ as probably only real solution.

[image]

Comment: It's exactly the WA's solution! I have a solution of this problem, but it's a very ugly solution. Mysterious problem!

Comment: There should be no doubt about the fact that the non-real solutions are quite "ugly". However, I think, it would be very good to expose them explicitly.

Comment: @Batominosvki: your solution is certainly formed by the roots of  $$(a\pm\sqrt{a^2-2ax^2-x}+57)^5-2ax^5+32a=0$$ for a certain value of the parameter 2a (instead of a), is not it?

Comment: What software did you use to plot the curves?

Comment: Just write the equations in https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Answer (score 0):

By adding these two equations I ended up in a quite symmetric term

$$x^5+y^5+5[(1+xy)(y+x)(y-x+1)]~=~-41$$

I would also recommend to use the fact that you can write any $(x+y)^n$ only in terms of $xy$ and $(x+y)$ and the two $x^n,y^n$ like

$$(x+y)^3~=~x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$$

Maybe someone can proceed form there.