# Real single solution of an algebraic nonlinear system

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, symmetric-polynomials

Inspired from ["How.."](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865436/how-do-i-solve-this-algebra-problem) I extract the following problem that I have solved:

Prove that $(x, y) = (1, -2)$ is the only real solution of the system   $$\begin{cases}x^5+5(xy+1)(y-x^2)=16\\y^5+5(xy+1)(y^2+x)=-57\end{cases}$$

Comment: Computationally, one can verify that [`resultant[x^5+5(xy+1)(y-x^2)-16, y^5+5(xy+1)(y^2+x)+57, y]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B+x%5E5%2B5(xy%2B1)(y-x%5E2)+-+16+,+y%5E5%2B5(xy%2B1)(y%5E2%2Bx)+%2B+57+,+y+%5D) = $\,(x-1) (x^{12}-2x^{11}+x^{10}+25x^9-95 x^8+108x^7+419x^6-1482x^5+4150x^4-6605x^3+12191x^2-5617x+19531) (x^{12}+3x^{11}+6x^{10}+35x^9+135x^8+233x^7+129 x^6+398 x^5+1315x^4+1340 x^3+1116x^2+343x+71)\,$ where the $12^{th}$ degree factors have no real roots, which leaves only $\,x=1\,$. That's hardly something anyone would dream of doing by hand, though.

Comment: Extraordinary the result given by computer (I ignore these technological prodigies). I suggest you give it as an answer in the post of the link above. Regarding my problem, this consists in proving, by more modest means (though not so easy) that of the other roots of your resultant in $x$ of the system, none can be real, which is suggested by the graphs of the two curves in play but as both are not bounded the graphics are not enough as a proof.

Comment: I only left the comment here as evidence that's it's technically possible to answer the question, albeit awfully impractical (not to mention downright ugly). The number of real roots of real polynomials can also be algorithmically determined, see for example [Criteria to determine whether a real-coefficient polynomial has real root?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/20946), though that's not pretty, either. As for the linked post, I left a comment there yesterday which went unanswered, and I guess the question could possibly be a case of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: @dxiv: Very interesting your references. Thanks.